# How to disable physical back button when the $ionicPopup is showing

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

Recently I made an app built with ionic framework. Now I'am having trouble with the back button when the pop-up is showing. The pop-up closes when I press physical back button, now I need it to be showing when I press physical back button, so I find all the solution to disable the physical back button, but none worked. Is there anyone who can help me with this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can override the back button method for when popup is showing.

```
var myNullAction = $ionicPlatform.registerBackButtonAction(function(){
  // do nothing
}, 401);
```

401 is a priority higher than the action id for dismissing a popup. Note, this will also run and therefore do nothing on any of the other lower priority actions e.g. close side menu/return to previous view. So you may need to add functionality for that yourself.

So a good idea would be to run this method just before showing your popup. The method will return a function, which should then be called to deregister this callback so that normal functionality is resumed for lower priority actions e.g.:

```
 myPopup.then(function(res) {
    myNullAction();
  });
```

More info here: http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/service/%24ionicPlatform/